# x-editable: callback for cancel evert

Tags: javascript, x-editable

For Twitter Bootstrap X Editable (https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html), there's a callback for success, and for error. But there's nothing for cancel. Is there a way to listen for the cancel event for a specific editable?

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer ?

Comment: forgot to, thanks for the bump

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
  $('#element', this.$e).editable({
    type: 'text',
    toggle: 'manual',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
      //some action
    }.bind(this)
  }).on('hidden', function(e, reason) {
    if (reason == "cancel") {
      //some action
    }
  });
```

You can define a listener on "hidden" and check the reason for cancel or submit or manual.